# Firefox parent did not displaying

Tags: html, css, firefox

I seem to be having a problem with Firefox displaying my web page. It is having difficulty displaying the styling of a parent div. Here are some pictures.

This is how it should look.
[My website in Chrome/IE http://www.lackeycomputing.com/sun_coast_crane/pictures/sunCoastCraneChrome.PNG](http://www.lackeycomputing.com/sun_coast_crane/pictures/sunCoastCraneChrome.PNG)

This is how it looks in Firefox
[My website in Firefox http://www.lackeycomputing.com/sun_coast_crane/pictures/sunCoastCraneFireFox.PNG](http://www.lackeycomputing.com/sun_coast_crane/pictures/sunCoastCraneFireFox.PNG)

It seems as though neither the #wrapper div, nor the .content divs are styled properly. I have no idea why this is happening.

Here are the links to the HTML and CSS.

http://lackeycomputing.com/sun_coast_crane/index.html

http://lackeycomputing.com/sun_coast_crane/css/styles.css

Any ideas?

Comment: -1, isolate the issue

Comment: Before anything else, your page load time is terrible.  Part of the reason is you are serving 3.7 MB photos that are also being scaled down.

Comment: Firebug or even the default inspector would be the tools you need.

Comment: @BLaZuRE I will be fixing that soon. This seemed to be a more pressing issue.

Comment: I also suggest you make the page less wide. 1280px is too wide for a non-responsive site. 960px used to be the recommended width for content.

Comment: @Nile Sorry. I fixed the problem, but thanks for giving the time anyway. I didn't really have any idea where to start with it.

Comment: @yitwail That is something I might do. I designed the site to work in landscape. I will probably add better smartphone portrait support later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add class clearfix to your div#main

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `<hr>` tag and troubleshoot from there.  It may have something to do with browser compatibility of the HTML5 standard, since the `<hr>` tag has changed into a *thematic break* instead of just a *horizontal rule*.  It probably is also your styling, which I haven't checked closely.  Use Firebug of Web Developer Toolbar to troubleshoot your website issues.

Comment: It was a problem with height: 100% that I was using in chrome.

Comment: clearfix solved the problem